# Mysterious CSS Selectors in Chrome Profiles

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, css-selectors

I am running my website through the "Collect CSS Selector Profile" feature in my Chrome Developer Tools.  My response time is alright with the exception of a long selector at the very top of my document, http://danyuschick.com/:1 according to the profiler.

The selectors in question are:

```
.under_ads, .undertimyads, .uniAds, .uniblue-text-ad, .unit-ad, .universalboxADVBOX01, .universalboxADVBOX03, .universalboxADVBOX04a, .us-advertisement, .us-txt-ad, .useful_banner_manager_rotation_widget, .usenext, .v5rc_336x280ad, .vAd_160x600, .ve2_post_adsense, .vert-ad, .vert-ads, .vert-adsBlock, .vertad, .vertical-adsense, .verticalAd, .vertical_ad, .vertical_ads, .verysmallads, .vidadtext, .video-ad-short, .video-adtech-mpu-ad, .videoAd-wrapper, .videoBoxAd, .video_ad, .video_ads, .video_ads_overdiv, .video_ads_overdiv2, .video_advertisement_box, .view-image-ads, .view-promo-mpu-right, .view-site-ads, .viewContentItemAd, .view_ad, .view_ads_advertisements, .view_ads_bottom_bg, .view_ads_bottom_bg_middle, .view_ads_content_bg, .view_ads_top_bg, .view_ads_top_bg_middle, .view_rig_ad, .views-field-field-adbox-1, .views-field-field-adbox-2, .virgin-mpu, .vs-advert-300x250, .vsw-ads, .vswAdContainer, .vt_h1_ad, .vxp_ad300x250, .wAdvert, .w_AdExternal, .wa_adsbottom, .wahAd, .wahAdRight, .wallAd, .wall_ad, .wall_ad_hd, .wallad, .wantads, .waterfall-ad-anchor, .wazi-ad-link, .wdp_ad, .wdp_adDiv, .wdt_ads, .weather-ad-wrapper, .weatherAdSpot, .weather_ad, .weatherad, .web-result-sponsored, .webad-cnt, .webads336x280, .well-ad, .wfb-ad, .wide-ad, .wide-ad-container, .wide-ad-outer, .wide-advert, .wide-footer-ad, .wide-header-ad, .wide-skyscraper-ad, .wideAdTable, .widePageAd, .wide_ad, .wide_ad_unit, .wide_ad_unit_top, .wide_ads, .wide_google_ads, .wide_grey_ad_box, .wideadbox, .widget-ad, .widget-ad-codes, .widget-ad-zone, .widget-ad300x250, .widget-ads, .widget-adsense, .widget-adv, .widget-advertisement, .widget-entry-ads-160, .widget-text-ad, .widgetYahooAds, .widget_ad, .widget_ad-widget, .widget_ad125, .widget_ad_boxes_widget, .widget_ad_rotator, .widget_adrotate_widgets, .widget_ads, .widget_adsensem, .widget_adsensewidget, .widget_advert_widget, .widget_advertisement, .widget_advertisements, .widget_advertisment, .widget_advwidget, .widget_bestgoogleadsense, .widget_customadvertising, .widget_cxad, .widget_econaabachoadswidget, .widget_internationaladserverwidget, .widget_ione-dart-ad, .widget_island_ad, .widget_maxbannerads, .widget_new_sponsored_content, .widget_sdac_bottom_ad_widget, .widget_sdac_companion_video_ad_widget, .widget_sdac_footer_ads_widget, .widget_sdac_skyscraper_ad_widget, .widget_sdac_top_ad_widget, .widget_sidebaradwidget, .widget_sponsored_content, .widget_uds-ads, .widget_vb_sidebar_ad, .widget_wnd_ad_widget, .widgetads, .width-ad-slug, .wikia-ad, .wikia_ad_placeholder, .wingadblock, .wis_adControl, .wl-ad, .wn-ad, .wnIframeAd, .wnMultiAd, .wp125_write_ads_widget, .wp125ad, .wp125ad_1, .wp125ad_2, .wpInsertInPostAd, .wp_bannerize, .wpadvert, .wpn_ad_content, .wrap-ads, .wrapper-ad, .wrapper-ad-sidecol, .wrapper_ad, .ws-ad, .wsSearchResultsRightSponsoredLinks, .wsSponsoredLinksRight, .wsTopSposoredLinks, .wx-adchoices, .wx-gptADS, .x01-ad, .x03-adunit, .x04-adunit, .x81_ad_detail, .xads-blk-bottom-hld, .xads-blk-top-hld, .xads-blk-top2-hld, .xads-blk1, .xads-blk2, .xads-ojedn, .xmlad, .xs_epic_circ_ad, .xs_epic_sponsor_label, .xtopadvert, .y-ads, .y-ads-wide, .y5_ads, .y5_ads2, .y7-advertisement, .y7adHEAD, .y7adS, .y7s-lrec, .yaAds, .yahoo-banner-ad-container, .yahoo-sponsored, .yahoo-sponsored-links, .yahooAd, .yahooAds, .yahooContentMatch, .yahoo_ad, .yahoo_ads, .yahooad-image, .yahooad-urlline, .yahooads, .yahootextads_content_bottom, .yan-sponsored, .yat-ad, .yellow_ad, .yfi-fp-ad-logo, .ygrp-ad, .yieldads-160x600, .yieldads-728x90, .yl-lrec-wrap, .yls-sponlink, .yom-ad, .youradhere, .youtubeSuperLeaderBoardAdHolder, .youtubeSuperLeaderOverallAdArea, .yrail_ad_wrap, .yrail_ads, .ysmsponsor, .ysp-dynamic-ad, .ysponsor, .yui3-ad, .yw-ad, .z-sponsored-block, .zRightAdNote, .zc-grid-ad, .zc-grid-position-ad, [onclick^="window.open('http://adultfriendfinder.com/search/"], a[href$="/vghd.shtml"], a[href*="/adrotate/adrotate-out.php?"], a[href^=" http://www.drowle.com/"], a[href^="http://NowDownloadAll.com"], a[href^="http://ad-apac.doubleclick.net/"], a[href^="http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/"], a[href^="http://ad.yieldmanager.com/"], a[href^="http://ads.affbuzzads.com/"], a[href^="http://ads.pheedo.com/"], a[href^="http://adserving.liveuniversenetwork.com/"], a[href^="http://adsrv.keycaptcha.com"], a[href^="http://affiliate.glbtracker.com/"], a[href^="http://amzn.to/"] > img[src^="data"], a[href^="http://api.ringtonematcher.com/"], a[href^="http://bonusfapturbo.nmvsite.com/"], a[href^="http://bs.serving-sys.com/"], a[href^="http://buysellads.com/"], a[href^="http://cinema.friendscout24.de?"], a[href^="http://codec.codecm.com/"], a[href^="http://connectlinking6.com/"], a[href^="http://data.ad.yieldmanager.net/"], a[href^="http://down1oads.com/"], a[href^="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/"], a[href^="http://fusionads.net"], a[href^="http://galleries.pinballpublishernetwork.com/"], a[href^="http://galleries.securewebsiteaccess.com/"], a[href^="http://games.ucoz.ru/"][target="_blank"], a[href^="http://greensmoke.com/"], a[href^="http://install.securewebsiteaccess.com/"], a[href^="http://latestdownloads.net/download.php?"], a[href^="http://lp.ilivid.com/"], a[href^="http://lp.ncdownloader.com/"], a[href^="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/"], a[href^="http://secure.hostgator.com/~affiliat/"], a[href^="http://secure.signup-page.com/"], a[href^="http://secure.signup-way.com/"], a[href^="http://tour.affbuzzads.com/"], a[href^="http://tracking.crazylead.com/"], a[href^="http://ul.to/ref/"], a[href^="http://www.1clickdownloader.com/"], a[href^="http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/AF_"], a[href^="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?"], a[href^="http://www.adxpansion.com"], a[href^="http://www.babylon.com/welcome/index?affID"], a[href^="http://www.bet365.com/home/?affiliate"], a[href^="http://www.bluehost.com/track/"], a[href^="http://www.dealcent.com/register.php?affid="], a[href^="http://www.down1oads.com/"], a[href^="http://www.download-provider.org/"], a[href^="http://www.downloadweb.org/"], a[href^="http://www.drowle.com/"], a[href^="http://www.faceporn.net/free?"], a[href^="http://www.firstclass-download.com/"], a[href^="http://www.firstload.com/affiliate/"], a[href^="http://www.firstload.de/affiliate/"], a[href^="http://www.friendlyduck.com/AF_"], a[href^="http://www.graboid.com/affiliates/"], a[href^="http://www.incredimail.com/?id="], a[href^="http://www.ireel.com/signup?ref"], a[href^="http://www.liutilities.com/aff"], a[href^="http://www.liutilities.com/products/campaigns/adv/"], a[href^="http://www.my-dirty-hobby.com/?sub="], a[href^="http://www.myfreepaysite.com/sfw.php?aid"], a[href^="http://www.myfreepaysite.com/sfw_int.php?aid"], a[href^="http://www.myvpn.pro/"], a[href^="http://www.on2url.com/app/adtrack.asp"], a[href^="http://www.pheedo.com/"], a[href^="http://www.quick-torrent.com/download.html?aff"], a[href^="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/"], a[href^="http://www.seekbang.com/cs/"], a[href^="http://www.sex.com/?utm_source="], a[href^="http://www.sfippa.com/"], a[href^="http://www.streamate.com/exports/"], a[href^="http://www.text-link-ads.com/"], a[href^="http://www.uniblue.com/cm/"], a[href^="http://www.urmediazone.com/signup"], a[href^="http://www.webtrackerplus.com/"], a[href^="http://www1.clickdownloader.com/"], a[href^="http://wxdownloadmanager.com/dl/"], a[href^="https://secure.eveonline.com/ft/?aid="], a[href^="https://www.share-online.biz/affiliate/"], div[id^="YFBMSN"], iframe[src^="http://ad.yieldmanager.com/"], iframe[src^="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/"], iframe[src^="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/"], img[alt^="Fuckbook"], input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/AF_"], input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.friendlyduck.com/AF_"], #center_col > div[style="font-size:14px;margin-right:0;min-height:5px"] > div[style="font-size:14px;margin:0 4px;padding:1px 5px;background:#fff8e7"], #cnt #center_col > #res > #topstuff > .ts, #mbEnd[cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="0"], #mclip_container:last-child, #mn #center_col > div > h2.spon:first-child, #mn #center_col > div > h2.spon:first-child + ol:last-child, #resultspanel > #topads, #rhs_block > #mbEnd, #rhs_block > .ts[cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="0"][style="padding:0"], #rhswrapper > #rhssection[border="0"][bgcolor="#ffffff"], #ssmiwdiv[jsdisplay], #tads.c, #tadsb.c, #tadsto.c, #topstuff > #tads, .GB3L-QEDGY .GB3L-QEDF- > .GB3L-QEDE-, .ch[onclick="ga(this,event)"], .commercial-unit-desktop-rhs, .lads[width="100%"][style="background:#FFF8DD"], .mw > #rcnt > #center_col > #taw > #tvcap > .c, .mw > #rcnt > #center_col > #taw > .c, .ra[align="left"][width="30%"], .ra[align="right"][width="30%"], .ra[width="30%"][align="right"] + table[width="70%"][cellpadding="0"], .rhsvw[style="background-color:#fff;margin:0 0 14px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-top:1px;"], #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle, #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle, #LovelabAdoftheDay, #ad-div-leaderboard, #adFlashDiv, #dfp_ad_DictHome_300x250, #dfp_ad_DictHome_728x90, #dfp_ad_InternalAdX_300x250_right, #grouponAdContainer, #sbads-top, #vidAdTop, .InternalAdPanel1, .MediumRectangleAdPanel, .TopLeaderboardAdPanel, .ads_after, .ads_before, .ads_main, .adv-300-1, .advertisement-content, .cdo-dicthomepage-btm-ad, .display_ad, .featured-sponsors, .rbRectAd, #AD_banner, #AdColumn, #AdContainer, #AdHeader, #AdImage, #Adcode, #AdvertiseFrame, #BottomAdContainer, #ContentAd, #PreRollAd, #RightAdBlock, #TopAd, #ad-background, #ad-container, #ad-header, #ad-header-728x90, #ad-leaderboard, #ad-main, #ad-top, #ad-top-banner-placeholder, #ad-top-wrapper, #ad-unit, #ad-wrapper, #ad468, #ad728, #ad728x90, #adBanner, #adBelt, #adComponentWrapper, #adDiv, #adFrame, #adGallery, #adHeader, #adHolder, #adLayer, #adLeader, #adPosition0, #adText, #adWrapper, #ad_1, #ad_2, #ad_3, #ad_4, #ad_5, #ad_728_90, #ad_area, #ad_banner, #ad_center, #ad_cont, #ad_content, #ad_header, #ad_leaderboard, #ad_overlay, #ad_overlay_countdown, #ad_space, #ad_square, #ad_table, #ad_unit, #ad_wrap, #ad_wrapper, #adbackground, #adbanner, #adbar, #adblock, #adbody, #adbox, #adcode, #adcontainer, #adcontent, #adhead, #adlayer, #adposition3, #adright, #adsHeader, #ads_bottom, #ads_right, #ads_top, #ads_wrapper, #adsdiv, #adsense, #adsense_block, #adsense_inline, #adspace, #adspace_top, #adspot-300x250-pos-1, #adspot-300x250-pos-2, #adtext, #adtop, #adv-masthead, #adv-top, #advert1, #advert2, #advertisetop, #advertising_wrapper, #advtop, #adwrapper, #banner-ad, #bannerAd, #bannerAdWrapper, #banner_topad, #bannerad, #bigAd, #bigad, #bottom_ad, #cmn_ad_tag_head, #companionAd, #content-header-ad, #contentAd, #content_ads, #content_adv, #contentad, #dart-container-728x90, #dfp_ad_Entry_728x90, #divAd, #div_prerollAd_1, #download_ad, #featuread, #featuredAds, #footer_ad, #footer_ads, #game-ad, #google_ads_frame, #google_ads_frame1_anchor, #googlead, #head-ad, #header-ads, #headerAd, #headerAdContainer, #header_ad, #homead, #ka_adRightSkyscraperWide, #leaderAd, #leaderBoardAd, #leaderboard-ad, #left_ads, #leftad, #logoAd, #logo_ad, #mainAd, #main_ad, #mpu2, #mpu2_container, #mpu_container, #msad, #myAd, #pre_advertising_wrapper, #prerollAd, #printads, #promo-ad, #right_ads, #right_adsense, #searchAd, #search_ads, #sideAd, #side_ads, #sidebar-ads, #sidebar_ads, #skybox-ad, #sponsorAdDiv, #takeover_ad, #top-ad, #top-advertisements, #topAd, #topAdSpace, #topAdSpace_div, #topAdvert, #topBannerAd, #top_ad, #top_ads, #topad, #topbannerad, #videoAd, .ADBAR, .AdBody:not(body), .AdBox, .AdInfo, .AdTitle, .AdvertContainer, .HomeAds, .RelatedAds, .SponsoredContent, .ad-banner, .ad-bigbox, .ad-block, .ad-button, .ad-display, .ad-enabled, .ad-holder, .ad-img, .ad-inner, .ad-item, .ad-leaderboard, .ad-left, .ad-links, .ad-right, .ad-section, .ad-sidebar, .ad-square, .ad-stack, .ad-text, .ad-top, .ad-unit, .ad-unit-300-wrapper, .ad-vertical-container, .ad-wide, .ad-wrap, .ad-wrapper, .ad160, .ad300, .ad728, .ad90, .adBlock, .adBottomBoard, .adBox, .adContent, .adDiv, .adElement, .adFrame, .adHeader, .adHeaderblack, .adHeadline, .adHolder, .adHoldert, .adImg, .adItem, .adLink, .adMiddle, .adMod, .adModule, .adPanel, .adResult, .adRight, .adRotator, .adSpace, .adText, .adTitle, .adTopHome, .adWidget, .adWrap, .ad_1, .ad_160, .ad_160x600, .ad_2, .ad_3, .ad_728x90, .ad_Right, .ad_body, .ad_container, .ad_description, .ad_global_header, .ad_head_rectangle, .ad_header, .ad_item, .ad_leaderboard, .ad_middle, .ad_promo, .ad_space, .ad_text, .ad_title, .ad_wrap, .ad_wrapper, .adarea, .adbanner, .adbar, .adbutton, .adcolumn, .adcont, .addiv, .adframe, .adholder, .adinfo, .adlink, .adlist, .admain, .adpic, .adright, .adrow1, .adrow2, .ads-area, .ads-col, .ads-header, .ads-inline, .ads-item, .ads-section, .ads-title, .ads-top, .adsBlock, .ads_catDiv, .ads_div, .ads_top, .ads_wrapper, .adsbottombox, .adscontainer, .adshome, .adside, .adslot_blurred, .adspace, .adtile, .adv_300, .advert-block, .advert-box, .advert-container, .advert-content, .advert-horizontal, .advert2, .advertColumn, .advertContainer, .advert_container, .advert_list, .advertbox, .advertisement-1, .advertisement-swimlane, .advertiser, .advertising_block, .advertisment, .advertorial, .adwords, .article_ad, .banner-ads, .banner_728x90, .banner_ad, .bannerad, .block-ad, .blog-ads, .bottom-ad, .bottomAds, .bottom_ad_block, .box-ads, .boxad, .category-ad, .container_ad, .container_row_ad, .contentAd, .content_ads, .featuredAdBox, .flash-advertisement, .footer-ad, .footer-ads, .gallery-ad, .google-ad, .google-sponsored, .header-ad, .headerAd, .header_ad, .header_ad_center, .header_advert, .headerad, .headerads, .home-ad, .homeAd, .homead, .homepage_ads, .horizontal_ad, .image-advertisement, .imgad, .inner_ad, .innerad, .interstitial_ad_wrapper, .ipsAd, .leaderboard-ad, .leaderboard-ads, .leftAd, .leftad, .list-ad, .logo-ad, .marketing-ad, .mid_ad, .middle_AD, .module-ad, .newsAd, .oasad, .openx, .page_ad, .player_ad, .pm-ad, .post-ad, .post_ad, .post_ads, .postad, .promoAd, .publicidad, .rectangle_ad, .refreshAds, .region-top-ad-position, .reklam, .reklama, .right-ad, .rightAd, .right_ad, .right_ads_column, .rightad, .rightadv, .sb_adsNv2, .searchads, .side-ad, .single-ad, .singleAd, .sky_ad, .skyscraperAd, .small_ad, .smallads, .sponsor-box, .sponsoredLinks, .sponsoredtextlink_container, .sponsorlink, .text-ad, .textad, .textads, .top-ad, .topAds, .top_ad, .top_ad_div, .top_ads, .topads, .tower-ad, .wideAd, .withAds, a[href^="http://ad.doubleclick.net/"]
```

Can anyone explain where I may be able to find these or how I can remove them?  What may be triggering them?  I am at a loss.

http://www.DanYuschick.com

Comment: Ad links? Seems very suspicious.

Comment: Agreed.  Could this be something like a pharma hack?  I am unfamiliar with it and am searching it now.  Just not sure.

Comment: Aren't these selectors added by some Chrome extension like AdBlock?

Comment: You're right.  I paused my AdBlock, re-ran the profiler and those selectors were gone.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comment from Ilya Streltsyn, these selectors were being caused by the AdBlock extension that I was running.  Once disabled, these selectors were no longer being shown in the profiler.

Answer (score 4):

My app started showing `a[href^="http://www.faceporn.net/free?"]`

For me, his was caused by the uBlock extension in Safari 8.0.6.

Answer (score 2):

The entire  section of my website seems to be garbled sometimes when using uBlock.

These selectors are inserted into the  section:

```
#content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle
```

Which are also present in the OP.